# FileMaker Missing Function

Tags: filemaker, method-missing

```
Set Variable [$var1; Value: Get(ScriptParameter) & " "]
Set Variable [$Clip; Value: <Function Missing>(1;$SP)]
```

I realize that a plug in that is no longer installed with my version of Filemaker is causing this function to be missing. Could someone direct me to any potential plugins or functions that would replace this `<Function Missing>`

The script above is the entire script. There is no documentation. The $SP variable is probably the data within a certain column and row in my layout, and the goal of the script is to copy data from that column/row to the clipboard

Comment: "*Could someone direct me to any potential plugins or functions that would replace this <Function Missing>*" No, not without knowing what the function is supposed to do.

Comment: BTW, how difficult is it to install the plugin on your system, or open the solution on a system where the plugin is installed, read the function's name, then read the plugin's help for the function's description?

Comment: the goal of the script is to copy data from that column/row to the clipboard, and installing plug ins is not difficult. It's just time consuming finding the right one and testing to see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is `SetClipboardData` and the plugin for it is ScriptMaster. Make sure to install the `SetClipboardData` Module in your customized scriptmaster plugin.

Comment: Is this supposed to answer your question?

Comment: Yes, but your answers were useful too. I voted it up

Comment: Well, if you expect it to help someone in the future, you should at least add the name of the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

> Could someone direct me to any potential plugins or functions that
>   would replace this
>
> There is no documentation. The $SP variable is probably the data
>   within a certain column and row in my layout, and the goal of the
>   script is to copy data from that column/row to the clipboard.

If by that you mean copy the contents of a given **field** to the clipboard, this can be done natively by using the [Copy script step](http://www.filemaker.com/help/14/fmp/en/html/scripts_ref1.35.35.html#1028763), e.g.:

```
Copy [Select; YourTable::SomeField]
```

Note that this requires the target field to be placed on the current layout. The data copied will come from the current record (or from the first related record in the `YourTable` table, depending on the context of the current layout).

Alternatively, there are several plugins that offer a similar functionality with less restrictions (i.e. they can place data directly onto the clipboard). It would be helpful if you explained what your limitations are here - since you obviously used one of these and now you don't.